# How do I format Tesseract-OCR language settings within a .bat file's "for" command

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command-line, tesseract

I'm new to Windows cmd and .bat, and to Tesseract. But thanks to this list I've managed a couple of successes.

My first success was this cmd-window line:

```
tesseract.exe -l eng+lat+ita D:\TIFs\Convivio.tiff D:\TIFs\Convivio
```

My next success was the .bat file:

```
:Start
   @Echo off
   ECHO.
   ECHO This is a batch file
   ECHO.
   PAUSE
   BREAK=ON
   Set _SourcePath=D:\temp\TIFs\*.tif
   Set _OutputPath=D:\temp\TIFs\
   Set _Tesseract="D:\temp\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
:Convert
   For %%A in (%_SourcePath%) Do Echo Converting "%%A"...... &"D:\temp\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe" "%%A" "%_OutputPath%%%~nA"
   PAUSE
:End   
   Set "_SourcePath="
   Set "_OutputPath="
   Set "_Tesseract="
```

The problem now is how to include in the .bat file that"-l eng+lat+ita" bit from the cmd-window line.

I got the idea that this is possible from [an explanation of the "For" command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490909(v=technet.10)), which states that "**do** *command*" can be followed by "*CommandLineOptions*" (i.e., "-l eng+lat+ita").

Any help would be much appreciated... 'cause I've been banging my head on this one for hours now...

---

UPDATE: Found an alternative, but still would like an answer to my question.

I didn't know that "FOR" commands could be run from cmd. So, I pasted the folllowing line in the cmd window:

```
for %i in (*.tif) do "D:\temp\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe" -l eng+lat+ita "%i" "D:\temp\%~ni"
```

And, it worked!

As I say, though, how to do this with a .bat file?

Comment: Have you tried `For %%A in (%_SourcePath%) Do Echo Converting "%%A".... &%_Tesseract% -l eng+lat+ita "%%A" "%_OutputPath%%%~nA`  Since you've not shown the content of the variable `_Tesseract`, we're forced to make assumptions.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57619160/edit) to include sufficient code for us to replicate your issue. Currently we cannot see exactly how you created the variables, `%_SourcePath%`, `%_Tesseract%` and `%_OutputPath%`. We also do not know whether you're using this command within another command block either.

Comment: @Magoo Yup, tried that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:Start
@Echo off
ECHO.
ECHO This is a batch file
ECHO.
PAUSE
BREAK=ON
Set "_SourcePath=D:\temp\TIFs\*.tif"
Set "_OutputPath=D:\temp\TIFs"
Set "_Tesseract=D:\temp\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

:Convert
For %%A in ("%_SourcePath%") Do Echo Converting "%%A"...... &"%_Tesseract%" -l eng+lat+ita "%%A" "%_OutputPath%\%%~nA"
PAUSE
:End   
rem Set "_SourcePath="
rem Set "_OutputPath="
rem Set "_Tesseract="
GOTO :EOF
```

Since I don't have the `tesseract` utility, I used another. The above worked for me as I expected with that other utility, so no guarantees with `tesseract`.

It's normal practice to start a batch with `setlocal` which makes the clean-up effort unnecessary (hence `rem`med-out) since an implicit `endlocal` is executed when the batch terminates, restoring the environment to its initial state.

Assigning values containing quotes is valid but awkward when combining elements. Ditto terminating a value with a backslash. I've converted your code to my preferred syntax. Note that the syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

Will it work in your situation? Over to you to try.

Comment: Your solution worked with Tesseract too. Thank you... for both the solution and the "best practices" lesson.